# why enter and exit event not fire in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `scroll` plugin from [github](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy)
my **enter and exit** event not fire

here is my code , check link [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sKuOTlvZM3dCOwXfWOeR?p=preview)

```
$(function(){
    $('.t').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
        console.log('enter:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('.t').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
        console.log('exit:', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('#container .t').scrollSpy();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the scroll spy dynamically? If so you have to use the following
$(document).on() method.

```
  $(function(){
      $(document).on('scrollSpy:enter','.t',function(){
        console.log('enter:', $(this).attr('id'));
      });    
    });
```

Comment: no I am not adding dymicaaly see plunker.pls remove this answer

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is check if the spying elements are out of viewport. By default viewport is $(window). You can do this:

1. open scroll.js file
2. in the very first function find this: **var jWindow = $(window);**. This is a viewport.
3. you can either change it to **$('#container')** or delete it and initialize it in your html head section right after jQuery loading and before scroll.js like this: jWindow = $('#container').

Comment: see I tried first solution ut not working https://plnkr.co/edit/sKuOTlvZM3dCOwXfWOeR?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I see. So you can use the second way, just initialize it right after jQuery, like this: <script>var jWindow = $('#container');</script>, and delete it from scroll.js

Comment: Or you can initialize it right before the very first function in scroll.js opens. Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/UC5Bj6QNhM60VInOmUdk?p=preview

Comment: it is not working perfectly ..https://plnkr.co/edit/9oAmucEO0yvYDJJi8tGK?p=preview it fire first before div coming in view port